# Other Classes in Class arguments

Tags: dart

How can I set another Class as a Class constructor argument?

```dart
class MyClass {
     String message = 'myClass';

     void print() {
         print(this.message);
     }
}

class TestClass {
    var myClass;

    TestClass(???) {
        this.myClass = ???(); // ???
    }

    void debug() {
        print('DEBUG: ');
        this.myClass.print();
    }
}

main() {
 MyClass myClass;
 testClass(myClass);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't (at least not now). Your best option is to pass a builder function into the constructor.

```dart
class MyClass {
   var clazzBuilder;

   MyClass(this.clazzBuilder);

   doStuff() {
      var instance = clazzBuilder();
      :
   }
}
```

and then use it like this

```dart
var myTest = new MyClass(() => new Test());
var myProd = new MyClass(() => new Prod());
```

Note that the Dart team is planning to add both class concept (**.type**) and reflection to the language.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want actually do? Often people try to *apply paradigms from some languages in some other languages which isn't the best way to do some things*.

Answer (score 0):

Since `print` is an *instance* method and not a *static* method, you don't need to pass a *class* itself to `TestClass`, just an instance of it. Your program can be fixed like so:

```dart
class MyClass {
     String message = 'myClass';

     void print() {
         print(this.message);
     }
}

class TestClass {
    var myClass;

    TestClass(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    void debug() {
        print('DEBUG: ');
        this.myClass.print();
    }
}

main() {
 MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
 testClass(myClass);
}
```

Or, more idiomatically:

```dart
class MyClass {
   String message = 'myClass';

   void print() => print(message);
}

class TestClass {
  var myClass;

  TestClass(this.myClass);

  void debug() {
    print('DEBUG: ');
    myClass.print();
  }
}

main() {
  testClass(new MyClass());
}
```